# JavaFX: Strange offset for some fonts on Labels

Tags: css, fonts, javafx

On a javafx program I have a label, say:

```
<Label style="-fx-font: 25px 'Tahoma';" text="Hello World!!" />
```

I´ve been requested by the designer to change the font family, quite easy (I thought):

```
<Label style="-fx-font: 25px 'Algerian';" text="Hello World!!" />
```

The problem is the new font shows on screen with an odd offset that makes the text appear a bit higher and thus messing up the design.

Here is an [Output Example](http://es.tinypic.com/r/ixgxv7/5) of two labels side by side, left label has Tahoma font and looks OK, while the right label has 'HelveticaNeue' font and is much higher than the baseline.

I´ve solved the problem partially using Text components to replace the Label components with the boundsType attribute set to "VISUAL" instead of the default "LOGICAL".

```
<Text boundsType="VISUAL" style="-fx-font-family: 'Algerian'; -fx-font-size: 25px;" text="Hellow World!!" />
```

But it won't be nice to change the whole system's Label to Text components and there are labels inside buttons and other components where the same problem presents and would be difficult to substitute.

Is this a problem with these fonts? Some fonts work ok (Arial, Lucida Sans, MS Sans Serif), while others show this behaviour (Algerian, Helvetica).
I have those fonts installed on the OS and can even use them in MS Word without showing these offsets.

Is there an option on the Label component that does the same as the boundsType attribute of the Text component?

Hope someone knows what's happening, thanks in advanced.

Comment: I never setted up the fonts in the fxml itself, i always use the css file... You tried with that? Does it happen in all the OSs?

Comment: Hi Magcus, I use a css file also, but used inline css in the example so that it is clearer. I'm working on windows, and have seen the same behaviour on a collegue's MacOS. The app will finally run on a Linux, but I haven´t tried there yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Suggested Solution**

You probably need to [set a baseline alignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setAlignment%28javafx.geometry.Pos%29) (e.g. [Pos.BASELINE_LEFT](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html#BASELINE_LEFT)) for whatever container your labels are being placed inside.

**Explanatory Diagram**

The image below shows two different HBoxes one is colored pale blue, the other pale green.  The top box has an alignment of TOP_LEFT and the bottom of BASELINE_LEFT.  Inside each of the boxes are two red bordered labels in 30 point fonts.  The first label in each box is in the (Mac) system font and the second label is in Helvetica.  As you can see, when the alignment is on the baseline then the base of the Helvetica font lines up with the base of the System font.

[image: fontdemo]

**Sample FXML**

Here is an FXML file, which you can load in [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html), to produce the image above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<StackPane id="StackPane" style="-fx-background-color: cornsilk;" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <VBox alignment="TOP_LEFT" spacing="10.0">
      <children>
        <Label text="HBox Alignment - TOP_LEFT" />
        <HBox alignment="TOP_LEFT" spacing="5.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;">
          <children>
            <Label style="-fx-border-color: red;" text="System">
              <font>
                <Font size="30.0" fx:id="x1" />
              </font>
            </Label>
            <Label style="-fx-border-color:red;" text="Helvetica">
              <font>
                <Font name="Helvetica" size="30.0" fx:id="x2" />
              </font>
            </Label>
          </children>
        </HBox>
        <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
        <Label text="HBox Alignment - BASELINE_LEFT" />
        <HBox alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" spacing="5.0" style="-fx-background-color: palegreen;">
          <children>
            <Label font="$x1" style="-fx-border-color:red;" text="System" />
            <Label font="$x2" style="-fx-border-color:red;" text="Helvetica" />
          </children>
        </HBox>
      </children>
    </VBox>
  </children>
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
  </padding>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: I've tried with alignment "BASELINE" before, but didn't think in using it on the label's container. The result is much better than I had (at least the text is correctly aligned with respect to other labels in the component) however the offset still exists, but is moved to the bottom. This makes the container HBox go from 42px to 49px in height. Here is the [output](http://es.tinypic.com/r/dcxx82/5) of your example with the font the Designer gave me. That is not so bad, but when I try it with [buttons](http://es.tinypic.com/r/96m9vt/5), the result is not good. Is there something to do about it?

Comment: Agreed, button behaviour is not good.  I don't know what you can do about it.